# No apps open after switching to wayland

Tags: wayland, 21.04

Running 21.04, I switched from X11 to Wayland, and none of the apps apart from terminal and calculator seem to open.

There are no error messages to provide. When I click on an application (like Chrome, Brave, Firefox) it appears to be opening and then just "dies"?

I've seen in other threads that snaps don't work, but I'm not using any snaps. Effected apps appear to be widespread:

- Zoom
- Firefox
- Chrome
- Brave
- Slack
- Spotify
- VS Code

Again, there are no errors, how can I start to debug this to figure out what's going on?

Comment: You're not looking at a different workspace?

Comment: No, they literally don't start. Not even in terminal. I type `brave-browser` or `firefox`, and nothing happens. However, if I run `firefox` after `export MOZ_ENABLE_WAYLAND=1` firefox starts up. My understanding was that it should be getting started generally by xwayland (via x11 compatibility). But something is blocking that - and there are no messages </3

Comment: Please vote to close this question. It's not reproducible and the steps I took to repair it would not be appropriate for most people (downgrade kernel + downgrade mesa).